# Login.php script not working

Tags: php, html

Made this login script for website but whenever I try to submit I get the Index.php?Login=Error even though I ran the same SQL into database and it works fine. Bet I've made a tiny mistake.
[Picture of database rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkR5T.png)

```html
<?php

session_start();

include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' AND user_pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    header("Location: ../Index.php?login=Error");

} else {
    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
 header("Location: ../Index.php?login=success");
}
```

Comment: Try to print the content of `$row` first

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: FYI I think you may have a SQL Injection vulnerability in that $sql = ... line. Use a prepared statement instead. Also, echo $result and $conn, what do they show?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

To

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

However your code is open to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: When putting in actual user and pass I got a success. When trying a random user and pass it also came up with success.

Answer (score 0):

Problem come with your condition:

`if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

If you want to check row that match your query, just use: `if (!mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: When I use a random user and pass I get error, when I use actual user and pass I get error.

Comment: What error did you get? When you want to ask sth, please make sure that everyone can understand your problem. We can't help without any information.

Comment: header("Location: ../Index.php?login=Error"); <---- I get that in the url bar after submitting regardless of if I use actual account details or just inputting a random user/pass

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' AND user_pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
   $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
   $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
   $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
   $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
   $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
   header("Location: ../Index.php?login=success");
}else{
    header("Location: ../Index.php?login=Error");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest code to actually working. Before I would keep getting login=success in the url bar after running the code. But after changing it all to this I got a http 500 internal server error, so I don't actually know if it worked or not (I've tried other suggestions on this post aswell and none of them have done that)